# Question about mglfillelayer and MGLLineStyleLayer

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-ios

In mapbox_ios:
1. About MGLFillStyleLayer and MGLLineStyleLayer, how to set different styles (color, width, dotted line) for individual features.

2. A scene: if it is a separate polyhedron with no connection between the two surfaces in different places, but it is a feature, if I want to add more polyhedron to modify the graph (add a point and connect the two sides), how to modify the graph?

Hope to get help, thank you!

Comment: Would you like to add a polyhedron to a map, or is that a separate question?

Comment: 1 and 2 are separate problems.
In 2, I want to change the shape of a polyhedron by adding the form of a point, and I want these to be operated by the user, so I am not clear about how to associate the newly added coordinate point with polyhedron.

Comment: In geojson, each feature has a color attribute, and I want to directly color each feature through this attribute, but I haven't found a similar method in IOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your first question, you can style individual features within a style layer based on feature attributes.

Get started by [adding the layers](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/examples/shape-collection/) to your map. You could create your source, then style the layer's color based on the value in the feature attributes. Use the [`lineColor`](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/api/maps/5.2.0/Classes/MGLLineStyleLayer.html#/c:objc(cs)MGLLineStyleLayer(py)lineColor) property for your `MGLLineStyleLayer` and [`fillColor`](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/api/maps/5.2.0/Classes/MGLFillStyleLayer.html#/c:objc(cs)MGLFillStyleLayer(py)fillColor) to change the color of your `MGLFillStyleLayer`.

For example:

```
        let layer = MGLLineStyleLayer(identifier: "layer", source: source)
        layer.lineColor = NSExpression(forKeyPath: "color")
        style.addLayer(layer)
```

You can also create a dictionary with possible attribute values and the color you would like to use as values. [This example](https://github.com/mapbox/ios-sdk-examples/blob/master/Examples/Swift/MultipleImagesExample.swift) shows that approach by using icon images.

Comment: Jmkiley, thank you for your method. The first problem should have been solved. Today I studied the second problem, which is too difficult